# ajax処理中に画像を表示させたい

Tags: javascript, css, html5

現在は下記のような実装になっており、処理中画像は処理終了と同時に一瞬出現し、消えるという状態です。
これを、処理開始～処理終了まで表示したいのですが、方法が分かる方がいましたらご教授をお願いします。
[参考にしたサイト](http://jquery.nj-clucker.com/applied/now_loading/)

```js
function upload(form) {

    //処理中画像表示
    dispLoading();

      ～処理～

  $.ajax(
            {
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                data: fd,
                async: false,
　　　　　　　　　　　
              ～処理～

            })

    //処理中画像削除
    removeLoading();
}

// Loadingイメージ表示関数
function dispLoading(msg) {

    // 画面表示メッセージ
    var dispMsg = "";

    // 引数が空の場合は画像のみ
    if (msg != "") {

        dispMsg = "<div class='loadingMsg'>" + msg + "</div>";
    }

    // ローディング画像が表示されていない場合のみ表示
    if ($("#loading").size() == 0) {

        $("body").append("<div id='loading'>" + dispMsg + "</div>");
    }
}

// Loadingイメージ削除関数
function removeLoading() {

    // Loadingイメージを消す
    $("#loading").remove();
}
```

Comment: 「処理終了と同時に一瞬出現し、消える」とありますが、ソースを見た感じだと「処理開始と同時に～」でしょうか？それを `$.ajax` が完了するまで表示しておきたい、と。

Comment: いえ、現状は処理終了と同時に～です。
これを、処理開始～ajaxが完了するまで表示しておきたいのですが、上のソースだとまだ出来ていないです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

原因はブラウザのイベントループの処理方法何ですけど、ソリューションが二つあると思います：

1. 参考にされたサイトと同じように、`removeLoading()`を`complete`のファンクションに追加して、ajaxリクエストを非同期にする（`async: true`）。
2. ajaxリクエストをタイムアウトで呼ぶ：

```js
dispLoading();

setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: fd,
        async: false
    });

    removeLoading();
}, 0);
```

Comment: そのコードではAjaxリクエストが完了する前に `removeLoading()` してしまいませんか？

Comment: @unarist すみません。修正しました。

Comment: 解決することが出来ました。ありがとうございます